# GetJSON method only pulls the array but not specific fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

Here is my GetJSON method:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("/user", function (obj) {
       
        $.each(obj, function (key, value) {
            $("#usernames").append(value.firstname);
            console.log(obj);
            
        });
    });
    
});
```

When i use my GetJSON method to call faker data into the console, it calls the below,

```js
{users: Array(20)}
users: Array(20)
0: {id: 0, firstname: "Adolf", secondaryname: "Harvey", phone: "1-778-605-9725 x341", address: "54001 VonRueden Course", …}
1: {id: 1, firstname: "Cheyanne", secondaryname: "Bradtke", phone: "067.058.4419 x8766", address: "63788 Moen Green", …}
2: {id: 2, firstname: "Llewellyn", secondaryname: "Jacobi", phone: "(253) 989-2943", address: "41407 Buckridge Ports", …}
3: {id: 3, firstname: "Catherine", secondaryname: "Cremin", phone: "1-436-764-8803", address: "49099 Lockman Keys", …}
4: {id: 4, firstname: "Audie", secondaryname: "Walker", phone: "1-311-464-1789 x1129", address: "2769 Lehner Ville", …}
5: {id: 5, firstname: "Theo", secondaryname: "Jones", phone: "794-691-2506", address: "55864 Barton Skyway", …}
6: {id: 6, firstname: "Beth", secondaryname: "Parisian", phone: "057-914-8618", address: "247 Parisian Drive", …}
7: {id: 7, firstname: "Alvena", secondaryname: "Harber", phone: "(208) 182-2397 x09029", address: "793 Wiza Course", …}
8: {id: 8, firstname: "Elton", secondaryname: "Fahey", phone: "197.264.1849", address: "0309 Jackeline Points", …}
9: {id: 9, firstname: "Hattie", secondaryname: "Smith", phone: "(956) 048-2359", address: "5377 Kathryne Hills", …}
10: {id: 10, firstname: "Janice", secondaryname: "Bauch", phone: "(231) 310-1489", address: "8024 Kub Islands", …}
11: {id: 11, firstname: "Natalie", secondaryname: "Altenwerth", phone: "(234) 493-6145", address: "232 Blick Lodge", …}
12: {id: 12, firstname: "Jaren", secondaryname: "Armstrong", phone: "(309) 818-6424", address: "0691 Bechtelar Haven", …}
13: {id: 13, firstname: "Deshawn", secondaryname: "Renner", phone: "286.165.8830", address: "844 Brionna Streets", …}
14: {id: 14, firstname: "Mckenzie", secondaryname: "Greenholt", phone: "911-524-4888", address: "81754 Hayes Springs", …}
15: {id: 15, firstname: "Grayson", secondaryname: "Stamm", phone: "658.155.5440 x376", address: "653 Blick Junction", …}
16: {id: 16, firstname: "Serenity", secondaryname: "Ratke", phone: "558-344-2253", address: "725 Margret Knoll", …}
17: {id: 17, firstname: "Jaleel", secondaryname: "Bashirian", phone: "710.797.1506 x6542", address: "355 Alison Flats", …}
18: {id: 18, firstname: "Henri", secondaryname: "Cartwright", phone: "967-982-1096", address: "7106 Margarette Fall", …}
19: {id: 19, firstname: "Rhoda", secondaryname: "Ledner", phone: "877-064-1157 x237", address: "2826 Macejkovic Shoal", …}
length: 20
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

However if i change the "console.log(obj)" to "console.log(value.firstname)" i get undefined, would anyone know why this is?

Comment: It looks like the array value is JSON not another array. Try `console.log(value);` to see what the value is outputting.

Comment: It seems like it should work, but you can add a `debugger;` statement on line 5 and use your browser's developer tools to examine the `key` and `value` properties at that point.

Comment: Yeah, as @fyroc says, the each is going to iterate once, with the key being `users` and `value` being the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since obj is an object with a single key of users, you want to loop over your users element, rather than the obj.

```js
//$(document).ready(function () {
//    $.getJSON("/user", function (obj) {

var obj = {
  users: [
    {id: 0, firstname: "Adolf", secondaryname: "Harvey", phone: "1-778-605-9725 x341", address: "54001 VonRueden Course"},
    {id: 1, firstname: "Cheyanne", secondaryname: "Bradtke", phone: "067.058.4419 x8766", address: "63788 Moen Green"},
    {id: 2, firstname: "Llewellyn", secondaryname: "Jacobi", phone: "(253) 989-2943", address: "41407 Buckridge Ports"}
  ]
};

$.each(obj.users, function (key, value) {
  $("#usernames").append(value.firstname);
  console.log(value.firstname);
});
//    });
//});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="usernames"></div>
```

Comment: Great! Sorry for the late reply, but would there be a way to do this with faker data?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what faker data is. @JackD

Answer (score -1):

"console.log(value.firstname)" Is undefined because each item in the object is saved at a different index- ie "console.log(obj.[0]firstname)}" should give you the first name at index 0 (Adolf). You will need to write a for loop to iterate over the data:

```
for( let i = 0; i< obj.length; i++){
        console.log(obj[i].firstname); //etc experiment with console.log here
        $("#usernames").append(obj[i].firstname);
}
```

Comment: .forEach is an array method: https://codeburst.io/javascript-the-difference-between-foreach-and-for-in-992db038e4c2

Comment: Ah, crap, obj is not an array, but that means this logic wouldn't work as a for loop anyway.